# Empty Resultset, using JDBC with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, select, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I have a Java application which already works with a MySQL database. I also want that it is compatible with Microsoft SQL Server, so I added an alternative connection opportunity with a SQL Server (Express Version) database in the background. But the queries only return empty result sets.

What I've already done in SQL Server;

- I created a new user and mapped him to the selected database.
- I also inserted some dummy data. When I execute my query in SQL Server Management Studio, it will return the expected results, so I think the query should be correct.

  I also tried different configurations in SQL Server, but I still get empty result sets in my Java application.
- I gave the user the role memberships db_datawriter and db_datareader for the selected database (I don't know if this is necessary).
- For the whole server, I gave the use grant permissions to connect to any database, connect to sql, create any database, view any database.
- For the database I gave the user Delete, Execute, Select, Insert, Connect and Update grant permissions.

What already works in Java with the SQL Server database:

1. I can connect with the Server and the DB
2. I also can execute the query without getting any errors but the result set is always empty.

I really don't know where I have to look for my fault. I thought I didn't configured SQL Server correctly, because when I do the same thing with my MySQL database I get the correct result sets. But executing the query with the same user in SQL Server Management Studio, will also show the expected data.

Here is a code snippet which executes the SQL query and adding the rows into the Jtable.

```
public void TableShow(DefaultTableModel table_lin) 
{
    PreparedStatement ps_lin = null;
    ResultSet rs_tbl = null;
     try
     {
        
        String lin_sqltbl = "SELECT Linien.ID, Linien.lin_name, "
                + "Customer.cus_name FROM Customer INNER JOIN Linien "
                + "ON Customer.ID = Linien.cus_id";
        
         System.out.println(lin_sqltbl);
        
        
        ps_lin = this.conn.prepareStatement(lin_sqltbl);
        
        
        table_lin.setRowCount(0);
        table_lin.setColumnCount(0);
        
        
        rs_tbl = ps_lin.executeQuery();
        
        
        table_lin.addColumn("ID");
        table_lin.addColumn("Linie");
        table_lin.addColumn("Kunde");
        
        while(rs_tbl.next())
        {
            int col1 = rs_tbl.getInt("Linien.ID");
            String col2 = rs_tbl.getString("Linien.lin_name");
            String col3 = rs_tbl.getString("Customer.cus_name");
           
           
            Object[] row = {col1, col2, col3};
            System.out.println(i + ": " + row + "\n");
            table_lin.addRow(row);
        
        }
            
    }
    
    catch(SQLException ex) 
    ...
```

I will be very grateful if someone can give me a useful hint.

Comment: You created dummy data in SQL Server management studio. Are you sure you committed that data? I don't see any other obvious problems with your code, although the fact your connection is an instance field may hide some concurrent use issues. Consider posting a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/modifying-result-set-data-sample?view=sql-server-ver15):

I was having the same issue, and after adding the following (`ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`) to my connection statement, it is now returning data:

```
cnx.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```